# Simple Power Series Solutions for advanced applied math

Tags: power-series

First of all, the image is my question page.
[image]

Then, I have my answer for this question just don't know if it is right or not. If I am wrong, can you give me a suggestion?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reach this equation:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty(b-n)a_nx^n=0
$$
So $(b-n)a_n=0$ for every n. Hence, if b is not a natural number, then all $a_n$ are 0. And if $b$ is an integer then $a_b$ can be chosen arbitrarly so the solution would be:
$$
y=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}a_bx^b & b\in\mathbb{N}\\0&\text{otherwise} \end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and I will check my answer!